# How to speed up 'for loop' for searching Pixel value in Image in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I have written the following code in Python that finds the value of each pixel in 160x160 image and records the values where certain intensity is observed.

```
def red_finder(img,fname):
resolution=img.shape
reds=[] #array to add intensity pixels

centre=np.divide(resolution,2)
for y in range(resolution[1]):
    for x in range(resolution[0]):
    #print img[x,y]
        if np.all(img[x,y]!=0):
            reds.append([x,y])
reds=np.array(reds)
(redx,redy)=(np.mean(reds,axis=0))
proc=(np.mean(reds,axis=0))
xray=proc-centre
return (xray[1],xray[0])
```

I think,

```
for y in range(resolution[1]):
    for x in range(resolution[0]):
#print img[x,y]
    if np.all(img[x,y]!=0):
        reds.append([x,y])
```

this way of scanning each pixel is consuming a lot of time.

Is there any solution to speed the code as the image size is larger and sometimes it varies.

Thank you.

Comment: You would do well to try to speed it up yourself, and then post code so we can work with that. It's a bit more in the SO spirit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double for-loop can be replaced by a call to [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def red_finder(img):
    resolution = img.shape
    centre = np.divide(resolution, 2)
    redx, redy = np.where(img != 0)
    proc = (redx.mean(), redy.mean())
    xray = proc - centre
    return (xray[1], xray[0])
```

Note: I believe your code implies that `img` has 2 dimensions (otherwise `proc - center` would raise an error). Therefore `img[x, y]` is a scalar value. So `np.all(img[x, y] != 0)` is the same as `img[x, y] != 0`.

Comment: Nice. Whereas I posted another answer, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Beauty, its like 100x faster. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had added np.all(img[x,y]!=0) because somewhere I was trying to accept colored image. But yes, I essentially wanted it for grayscale. Thus, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a list comprehension? They usually go a bit faster than plain loops.

```
reds = [ [x,y] for x in range(resolution[0]) for y in range(resolution[1]) if np.all(img[x,y]!=0) ]
```

Apart from that, `np.all()` is pretty efficient because 1. it's written in C and 2. it stops at any value that is not satisfying the condition.

As noted in another answer, a way you can go faster in to replace your whole loop with a built-in NumPy function that does the same thing natively.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have commented #print img[x,y]

Comment: Thanks for this method. It's little slower. So I support unutbu answer.